# Paging in Postgres on a Left Join

Tags: postgresql

**Summary:**

I have data in a db that needs to be displayed client side. Up until this point it wasn't paged but now the data has grown to a point that it's noticeably slowing the connection down. So I want to page it.

**Setup:**

- Client side I'm using DataTables
- Server side I'm using F#
- The DB is postgres

**Problem**:

[image]

I have 3 tables, Tables [A , B, C]. Table A has a one to many relationship with tables B and C. So when I do a query like

`select * from A left join B on a.id = b.tableidb left join C on a.id = c.tableidc`

[image]

I would get 7 rows, which is fine. This is all the data I actually want. The problem really comes when we try and page

`select * from A left join B on a.id = b.tableidb left join C on a.id = c.tableidc limit 5 offset 0`

[image]

As you can see, it does in fact bring back only 5 rows. However, because of the left joins, we don't get the full set of data.

**Expected Solution**

What I'd like to say is something to the effect of *"Give me 5 rows from table A at offset 0, then left join on tables B and C"*

Is there a way to do this in postgres?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use subselects in the `FROM` clause.

All you have to do is limit the number of rows there:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM A
      ORDER BY a.id
      LIMIT 5) AS al
   LEFT JOIN b ON al.id = b.tableidb
   LEFT JOIN c on al.id = c.tableidc;
```

**Notes:**

1. Using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` does not make much sense.
2. If you consider paging, don't use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`.

   Rather, remember the last `a.id` you selected the first time and query `WHERE a.id > previous_a_id LIMIT 5`.

Comment: Ha I was just in the middle of trying to do a subselect! SO has a great rubber duck effect sometimes. Thanks for the answer. I'll use this. Much appreciated

Comment: @DragosRizescu Then you have to do something different.

Comment: @DragosRizescu If you cannot figure it out, perhaps ask another question. Comments are not really for new questions.